# How to inject a block after toolbar block?

Tags: layout, magento-1

i want to inject a block via a custom layout.xml, here is the layout from base theme

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                <!--
                    <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                    <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                    <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                -->
                <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>5</limit></action>
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

i want to inject a block right after toolbar.pthml, here is my current layout.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default> 
        <reference name="content">

                <block type="core/template" name="datefilter" template="datefilter/datefilter.phtml" after="product_list_toolbar" />

        </reference> 
    </default>
</layout>
```

how can i do that?

Comment: please show us your phtml code may be we can help you, and for `$this` is pointing to current block class

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

**toolbar** is render  in `list.phtml` file by using code `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>` default.

If you want to inject a block after block then your block reference code  should be `reference name="product_list"` from  `reference name="content"`.

and for render this block at list.phtml add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('datefilter') ?>` after  **`<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>`**

Also handler should be *`<catalog_category_view>`*  and *`<catalogsearch_result_index>`* from  *`<default>`*.

### Add co de in  Layout

```
    <catalogsearch_result_index> 
        <reference name="search_result_list"> <!-- for search page , it is diffenet block typ -->
                <block type="core/template" name="datefilter" template="datefilter/datefilter.phtml" after="product_list_toolbar" />
        </reference> 
    </catalogsearch_result_index>
       <catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <block type="core/template" name="datefilter" template="datefilter/datefilter.phtml" /> 
    </reference>
 </catalog_category_layered> 
       <catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <block type="core/template" name="datefilter" template="datefilter/datefilter.phtml" /> 
    </reference>
 </catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: i've tried, but the phtml was not displayed

Comment: have add the code `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('datefilter');?>` in list.phtml

Comment: added, but not display

Comment: aha syntax mistake ....  i have edit the code

Comment: tried before you edited, not work : (

Comment: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('datefilter/datefilter.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

i think because the block type is not catelog/product, so $this shouldn't be work

Comment: $this will works . Have tested `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('datefilter/datefilter.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>` and it works

Comment: i have test code that it working perfectly... May you have put code in  a layout  file which  is not calling.So suggestion to be add the layout code at catalog.xml

Answer (score 1):

As a Quick Fix in your `list.phtml` file you can add this line.  and your block would be added after this line `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>`
add below code.

**Solution 1:**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('datefilter/datefilter.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Or with your way you can do this way

**Solution 2:**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default> 
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar_pager">
         <block type="core/template" name="datefilter" template="datefilter/datefilter.phtml" after="product_list_toolbar" />
    </reference> 
</default>
```

and in your `app/design/frontend/YourPackge/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` file add below line

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('datefilter');?>`